# Open activity and Activity History Related list is not showing in lightning for Case

Tags: lightning, activityhistory

we are working on case object where we have added two related list (Open activity and Activity history) on page layout. The issue that we are facing is when we are on classic being any user (be it system admin or any end user) we can see both the related list, but as soon we move to lightning ,only system admin can see the open activity and activity history related list but end user cannot see that.  Also i found [an article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000314931&type=1) which says if activity timeline is enabled activity history may not appear on related list for lightning. Further since my org has Activity timeline enabled and system admin can see the two related list , so i guess it should be some permission related issue only but no luck in finding the same.

PS: I doesn't want to use single related list for this requirement . I actually want to utilize the classic page layout and related list quick link for flexipage

**Edited:**
System admin view [image]

Non system admin view [image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure why this has been voted negatively. if this can be easily found on internet and anything like that, please do comment along with voting negatively.

Comment: Is the same Case Lightning record page shared with system admin and non-system admin users ?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of desired view and the current view ?

Comment: @Shamina yes the same lightning record page is share with both system admin and no-system admin user

Comment: @prabuddhkumar added the screenshot for reference.

Comment: @RanjitMishra Try login as one of the non-admin user and check the user's personal settings in Lightning
under Settings > Display and Layout > Customize my pages > Choose Case > check if activity history related lists are selected.
Also check under Settings > Display and Layout > Record Page Settings > Under Default Activities View, might need to toggle between Activity Timeline or Related List

Comment: @Shamina activity related list are selected in setting, also we doesn't want to change the record page setting from activity timeline related list

Comment: @RanjitMishra ok. did you notice this issue since recent release ? what does salesforce support say about this issue ?

Comment: Maybe, you already checked, However, can you recheck these?
(1) Identify the user's profile and record type.
(2) based on that figure out which page layout is assigned to that user.
(3) Verify that related lists are added or not

Comment: @NaveenBayya page layout does have the related list

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000352066&type=1

Comment: Since others have already covered all the possible solutions, without the looking at the actual permission settings for the user, its difficult to point out the problem. As a last resort, have you checked out that the creating a brand new record page also exhibits the same behavior for non-admin users? This could point out any potential corruption in the existing record page which only Salesforce support may be able to help out.

Comment: Is it resolved?

Comment: @NaveenBayya,  no

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who finds this and is still looking for an answer - as of the current version of Salesforce it looks like you can either use the timeline view or the related list view of activities but not both. The following note is now displayed when the lightning page is edited:

The Open Activities and Activity History related lists show up only if the Activities View is set to Related Lists for the org or user.

[image]
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_records_record_activities_view.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Following are few things to check :

1. Lightning record page
2. Page layout

- check if the same **record page** and **page layout** are assigned to both the profiles. If not, add the open activities and the activity related list on the page layout.

3. Read access on the "**Related To**" field for both **Task** and **Event** standard object.

- check if the non-admin profile has access to this field, at least read access is required for these lists to show on quick links

Comment: All these are already taken care but still facing same issue